# How is the round damage calculated?

Tags: dota-autochess

At the end of every round, if you lose, you lose x HP.

Thing is, I can't seem to figure out the logic. I used to think it was 1 HP per star (the unupgraded units value being 1), but sometimes that doesn't seem to fit.

Also, you can see summons doing the damage animation, but do they count? Feels like that would be an exploit to get more damage out of rounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each unit deals damage based on [its level](https://dotaautochess.gamepedia.com/Unit_Level), equal to 1 + floor(level/3).